# applying templates results in more than one item as the value in some 'cast as' expression, value-of does not

Tags: xslt

I want to transform a TEI/xml document with list headings contained inside (nested) lists to html. Thus, when I encounter one of those headings, I need to have started the list handling before transforming the actual heading.

My (xslt-2.0) stylesheet ignores `head[(parent::list)]` elements and instead handles these cases in a template matching "list": This creates some environment ('section') and if the list has a "head" child, it applies a matching template for head[(parent::list)] in a non-default mode to the head child, before it proceeds by putting an `ul`/`ol` with the items. But this results in the following error message:

```
A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the value in 'cast as' expression
```

I cannot simply use `<xsl:value-of select="child::head">` (which does not result in an error) because the heading can contain other elements I need to render, e.g. pagebreak elements.

Here is a snippet of a **sample document**:

```
<div>
  <list>
    <head>
      <pb facs="facs:W0013-0005" n="[2]"/>
      <lb n="1"/>PRIMUS TOMUS,
    </head>
    <item>
      <lb n="2"/>De
      <list>
        <item><lb n="3"/>Potestate ecclesiae, prior et posterior.</item>
        <item><lb n="4"/>Potestate civili.</item>
      </list>
    </item>
  </list>
</div>
```

and here is a snippet of my **stylesheet**:

```
<!-- In a first approach, ignore headings when they are inside a list -->
<xsl:template match="head[(parent::list)]" />
<!-- Here is what should be done with them, but this needs to be called somewhere -->
<xsl:template match="head[(parent::list)]" mode="listIsDone">
  <h4>
<!-- this works, but is not what i need: <xsl:value-of select="."/> -->
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </h4>
</xsl:template>
<!-- Here is how headings (outside of lists) are handled -->
<xsl:template match="head[not(parent::list)]">
  <h3>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </h3>
</xsl:template>
<!-- Here is how lists are handled -->
<xsl:template match="list">
  <xsl:choose>
<!-- When the list contains a heading, then transform it according
     to the headings-inside-of-lists template -->
    <xsl:when test="child::head">
      <section>
        <xsl:for-each select="child::head"> 
          <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="listIsDone"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
<!-- Then add an unordered list for the list "contents"/items -->
        <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </xsl:when>
<!-- If the list does not contain a heading, add only the unordered list -->
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </ul>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This is the **html** I want to get:

```
<section>
  <h4><!-- Here begins output of the p-matching template --> | <div class="pageNumbers">
                <a class="pageNo" href="someURL-gotten-from-the-facs-attribute">11</a>
         </div><!-- Here ends output of the p-matching template -->
      PRIMUS TOMUS,
  </h4>
  <ul>
    <li> De
      <ul>
        <li>Potestate ecclesiae, prior et posterior.</li>
        <li>Potestate civili.</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

I hope this is sufficiently indicative of what I want to achieve and of the problem I am having. Shouldn't the `<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="listIsDone"/>` do what I want?

I could not find anything searching/googling for the error message that didn't concern "empty sequences as as the value in 'cast as' expression" or xsl functions which I am not using (in this place).

I have also just tried a *second approach*, with `call-template` did not yield the correct result either:

**stylesheet:**

```
<xsl:template name="list-heading">
    <xsl:param name="heading-node"/>
    <h4>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$heading-node" mode="listIsDone"/>
    </h4>
</xsl:template>
...
<!-- and the in the matching template for "list", just like above, only at the for-each it is: -->
  <xsl:for-each select="child::head"> 
    <xsl:call-template name="list-heading">
      <xsl:with-param name="heading-node">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

This does not render the other child elements (notably `<pb>`) of the heading...

FWIW, I want to do all this in eXist which internally somehow uses Saxon, I think. But don't ask me about details of these internal implementations, I did not understand enough of it when I tried to find out about them.
Thank you for any and all help

Comment: Your XSL looks rather elaborate. Could you include a sample of the desired HTML? Maybe there's an all different approach...

Comment: Please include the HTML into your question. :-)

Comment: @MarcusRickert, sorry for my confusion wrt comments/edits. I have to get used to the interface...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out **the initial approach was correct after all**.

The error was produced in some function that was called in a template much later in the process. Therefore it was triggered when I had the list heading treated with apply-templates, and it was not triggered when I used value-of or switched the mode *without adjusting all the other matching templates to kick in again*.

After the error (caused by using `xs:string($nodeA@xml:id)` when `nodeA` was in fact several nodes) was fixed, I could use this stylesheet to achieve exactly what I wanted:

```
<xsl:template match="head[not(parent::list)]">
    <h3>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </h3>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="list">
    <section>
        <xsl:for-each select="child::head">
            <h4>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </h4>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="node()[not(local-name()='head')]">
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </ul>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </section>
</xsl:template>
```

If I am not overlooking something this is a preferable approach because it is not using modes at all (less complexity), needs no repeating definition of templates (inside and outside of the list) and is generic with regards to the level of nesting of the lists.

Of course, it is highly embarrassing to have totally mis-guessed the place where the actual error occurred, and thus to have asked in the very wrong direction. (Well, at least I did mention the error message which however obviously did not help me nor anyone else in spotting the error outside of the stylesheet snippet I have posted.)

So I sincerely apologize for causing you to spend so many efforts when in fact the problem lay somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the requested output or would work in your setting, but just wanted to share following approach:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/> 
<xsl:template match="/*">
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="list[not(child::list)]"/>
 </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="list[not(child::list)]">
<section>
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="child::head">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="child::head"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
   <h3>
    <xsl:text>No header for this list</xsl:text>
   </h3>
  </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
 <ul>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="child::item/list" mode="list"/>
 </ul>
</section>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="head" >
<h4>
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="header"/>
</h4>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pb" mode="header"/>
<xsl:template match="lb" mode="header"/>

<xsl:template match="list" mode="list">
<xsl:for-each select="./item">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="list"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="item" mode="list">
<li>
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="listItem"/>
</li>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="item" mode="listItem"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For testing, I just added a 2nd list in your XML-example without header:

```
 <list>
  <item>
   <lb n="2"/>De
   <list>
    <item><lb n="3"/>Potestate ecclesiae, prior et posterior.</item>
    <item><lb n="4"/>Potestate civili.</item>
   </list>
  </item>
 </list>
```

Result:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <section>
   <h4>
     PRIMUS TOMUS,
   </h4>
   <ul>
     <li>Potestate ecclesiae, prior et posterior.</li>
     <li>Potestate civili.</li>
   </ul>
  </section>
  <section>
   <h3>No header for this list</h3>
   <ul>
     <li>Potestate ecclesiae, prior et posterior.</li>
     <li>Potestate civili.</li>
   </ul>
  </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

As I don't know what should be the header in case of missing header, I just added some default copy; and as I don't know how you want to handle the `<pb>` and `<lb>`, they're just matching an empty template that could be adjusted for the desired output.

**Update:** Approach above was posted before desired HTML-output was added in OP. Will adjust it to match the requirement later as I'm just at work now. One main difference of suggested solution is just to start with each outer list-entry and taking care about missing headers from top-down instead of starting at the inner list and checking for headers from there. As all entries necessary to generate the output of a separate section are available in the first template `match="list[not(child::list)]"`, I just think it's easier to proceed from there on.

**Update 2:** Adjusted template to match desired output, though there are some questions remaining.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/> 
<xsl:template match="/*">
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="list[not(child::list)]"/>
 </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="list[not(child::list)]">
<section>
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="child::head">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="child::head"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
   <h3>
    <xsl:text>No header for this list</xsl:text>
   </h3>
  </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="child::item" mode="listItem"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="child::item/list" mode="list"/>
  </li>
 </ul>
 </section>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="head" >
<h4>
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="header"/>
</h4>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pb" mode="header">
<xsl:variable name="facs" select="./@facs"/>
<xsl:variable name="pageNo" select="./@n"/>
<xsl:variable name="pageNoResolved" select="translate($pageNo, '[]', '')"/>
<!-- tbd: get href from facs with additional function -->
<!-- tbd: get pageNo from pageNo with additional function -->
<div class="pageNumbers">
 <a class="pageNo">
  <xsl:attribute name="href" select="$facs"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$pageNoResolved"/>
 </a>
</div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="lb" mode="header"/>

<xsl:template match="list" mode="list">
<ul>
 <xsl:for-each select="./item">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="list"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="item" mode="list">
<li>
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="listItem"/>
</li>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="item" mode="listItem">
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="cleaning"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="lb" mode="cleaning"/>
<xsl:template match="item" mode="cleaning"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

HTML Output:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <section>
     <h4>
       <div class="pageNumbers">
          <a class="pageNo" href="facs:W0013-0005">2</a>
       </div>
        PRIMUS TOMUS,
     </h4>
     <ul>
        <li>
           De
           <ul>
              <li>Potestate ecclesiae, prior et posterior.</li>
              <li>Potestate civili.</li>
           </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

Remaining questions are: should there always be " | " between `<h4>` and `<div>`? As I don't know if this can change I just added it as static text. And as I don't know about how the href and the pagenumber will be retrieved - as you mentioned href will be retrieved from the `facs`-attribute - I just added the values. In case pagenumber is just the value of the `n="[2]"`-attribute of `pb`, I just removed the brackets.

Comment: Does your solution imply that I need to define templates in several modes for any element that can occur both inside and outside such a list (i.e. `<head>`, `<pb/>`, `<lb/>` etc.)? There are a lot and I am somewhat reluctant to duplicate them for another mode. Also, I will need to understand your xslt better in order to test and adapt it. Give me some time to gnaw on it...

Comment: @awagner Just updated my answer a bit, and will come back to it later. And sorry that I didn't add some explanation to the xslt, just thought it would be rather self explaining.

Comment: @awagner Updated my answer again with new xslt, don't know if this'll work for you but the output matches your desired output. Only tested it with the xml-part provided in your question, so maybe there could be (resolveable) issues left.